# Creating a table method on a user defined type (like like 'nodes' on the XML data type)

Tags: sql-server, extension-methods, user-defined-functions, sqlclr, user-defined-types

I've created working SQLCLR-based user defined table-valued functions as well as user defined types.

What I want now is a method on a SQLCLR UDT that returns a table, similar to the `nodes` method on the XML data type.

The `TableDefinition` and `FillRowMethodName` properties of the `SqlMethod` attribute / decoration seem to imply that it should be possible, but nothing actually works. When I call the method like this (which I expect to fail):

```
SELECT @Instance.AsTable();
```

I get:

> invalid data type

which is not the same error I get if I call a SQLCLR table-valued function that way.

When I call like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @Instance.AsTable();
```

I get the (possibly expected) error:

> The table (and its columns) returned by a table-valued method need to be aliased.

When I call like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @Instance.AsTable() t(c1,c2);
```

It says:

> Table-valued function 'AsTable' cannot have a column alias

I had a feeling the problem might be related to the fact that table functions are expected to be static so I also tried implementing it as an extension method but in that case it won't even compile.  I get:

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Obviously I could implement it as a normal SQLCLR table function that expects a parameter of my UDT type.  In fact I've actually done this and `SELECT * FROM dbo.AsTable(@Instance);` works but I don't like that solution.  I'd really like to get this syntax to work:    `SELECT * FROM @Instance.AsTable() t(c1,c2);`

Here's one non-working version:

```
[SqlMethod(IsDeterministic = false, DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, OnNullCall=true
    , TableDefinition = "RowKey nvarchar(32),RowValue nvarchar(1000)"
    , FillRowMethodName = "FormatLanguageRow")]
public IEnumerable AllRows()
{
    return _rowCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible to create a method on a UDT that returns a table (i.e. returns `IEnumerable`). Your confusion regarding the two properties of the `SqlMethod` attribute are quite understandable as they are misleading. If you take a look at the MSDN page for [SqlMethodAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmethodattribute), you will see the following note in the "Remarks" section:

> SqlMethodAttribute inherits from a SqlFunctionAttribute, so SqlMethodAttribute inherits the **FillRowMethodName** and **TableDefinition** fields from SqlFunctionAttribute. Note that it is not possible to write a table-valued method, although the names of these fields might suggest that it is possible.

Outside of the work-around that you have already tried (i.e. creating a TVF), you could return the data as XML (i.e. `SqlXml`) from a UDT method. It certainly won't be as efficient as a streaming TVF, but it is returning a value that can be turned into a table inline via the `nodes()` method of the `XML` datatype.

---

**UPDATE (2017-01-16)**

I have formally submitted this as a Microsoft Connect suggestion:
[Allow CLR UDT to return IEnumerable / Table / TVF from a method ( SqlMethod ) like XML.nodes()](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898802-allow-clr-udt-to-return-ienumerable-table-tvf)

Comment: Now that connect is retired your link is dead.  I found it here but it no longer has any votes (except now mine!).
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898802-allow-clr-udt-to-return-ienumerable-table-tvf

Comment: @bielawski Thanks. Yes, Microsoft did a horrifically awful job of migrating from Connect to UserVoice by not forwarding any URLs. I have been slowly updating references in my answers but haven't found them all yet. I have now updated my answer here (and voted on that suggestion). Thanks again.